# Помощь с парсером

Tags: php

Добрый день, пишу шаблонизатор для своей cms и столкнулся с таким вопросом, есть код для обработки функций в шаблоне:

```
if (strpos($string, "{func:") !== false) {
        $string = preg_replace("'{func:(.+?)}(.+?){/func}'ies", "@\\1('\\2');", $string);
    }
```

Но этот код обрабатывает только функции с одним параметром, например:{func:date}H:i:s{/func}, но как быть в случае если у функции будет не один а несколько параметров ? Например пишу {func:date}H:i:s, {time}{/func} Этот кусок кода должен переводить время из time() в читаемый вид, но к сожалению в функцию подставляется только один параметр и получается что-то типа 14:49:03,1364229666. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, нужно подкорректировать код, что-бы он обрабатывал несколько параметров у функции!

я написал такое для парных параметров:

```
if (strpos($string, "{funcpaire:") !== false) {
        $string = preg_replace("'{funcpaire:(.+?)}(.+?),(.+?){/funcpaire}'ies", "@\\1('\\2','\\3');", $string);
    }
```

Но это ведь не выход, ведь параметров может быть и больше!

Comment: здравствуйте, я решил сделать велосипед, колеса я тоже сделаю собственные, подскажите пожалуйста как сделать, чтобы спицы не гнулись.

Answer (score 1):

Достаньте ОДИН параметр, а потом примените к нему

```
$parameters = explode(',',$parameter);
```

Выполните куски по-отдельности, как будто они пришли из разных {func:}{/func}
Потом склейте результат выполнения

```
$parameter = implode(',',$parameters);
```

и так же все вместе замените, как будто там был один сложный параметр.

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понял как выглядит "объект" указывающий на присутствие функции. Но можно сделать так :

**{func:fname}param1/param2/....{/func:fname}**

И искать вот такой регуляркой (**preg_match_all**):

**#{func\:([a-zA-Z0-9-_]*)}(.*){func\:\1}#**

После перебрать результаты поиска, вызвать необходимую функцию и с помощью **str_replace** заменить объект функции в шаблоне на результат работы вызванной функции.

Сам пишу **CMS** под нужды, много пришлось думать над этим)